# how to run this file removing main

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Hello guys I am learning java from this site. I want to make the java file without putting main so that it will be easy to connect with other file. I mean I want to make this sub file. So can you guys help me to remove the main from this file and run it.

Here is my code

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JColorChooser;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/* ColorChooserDemo.java requires no other files. */
public class jptborder extends JPanel{

protected JColorChooser tcc;
protected JLabel banner;

public jptborder() {
super(new BorderLayout());

//Set up the banner at the top of the window
banner = new JLabel("Welcome To this border Example",
JLabel.CENTER);
banner.setForeground(Color.red);
//banner.setBackground(Color.blue);
banner.setOpaque(true);
banner.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 24));
banner.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450, 65));

JPanel bannerPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
bannerPanel.add(banner, BorderLayout.CENTER);
bannerPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Welcome"));

add(bannerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

}
public static void createAndShowGUI() {
//Create and set up the window.
JFrame frame = new JFrame("jptBorder");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

//Create and set up the content pane.
JComponent newContentPane = new jptborder();
newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

//Display the window.
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
//Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
//creating and showing this application's GUI.
javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
createAndShowGUI();
}
});
}
}
```

Comment: You just remove the main method from the code above (and even that is not necessary), create a main method in another java file, compile the other file and run it. How isn't this working for you? Please explain exactly where you may be stuck.

Comment: Please format your code above so that it is readable.

Comment: call from other class... classObject.method()

Comment: Further to the comment of @HovercraftFullOfEels  Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks. The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow. Your failure to acknowledge the comment or fix that mess suggests that you see us as your servants.  We are not.  Show some effort or expect your questions to be closed.

Answer (score 2):

Create another class in another file and move the main method into it.

To learn more: [JLS 12. Execution](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html) and [The Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html).

**JPTBorderLauncher.java**

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class JPTBorderLauncher extends JFrame {
   public JPTBorderLauncher() {
      super( "jptBorder" );
      setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
      add( new jptborder());
      pack();
      setVisible( true );
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         @Override public void run() { new JPTBorderLauncher(); }});
   }
}
```

**jptborder.java**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JColorChooser;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class jptborder
   extends
      JPanel
{
   protected JColorChooser tcc;
   protected JLabel        banner;

   public jptborder() {
      super( new BorderLayout() );
      banner = new JLabel( "Welcome To this border Example",
                           SwingConstants.CENTER );
      banner.setForeground( Color.red );
      banner.setOpaque( true );
      banner.setFont( new Font( "Arial", Font.BOLD, 24 ) );
      banner.setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 450, 65 ) );
      JPanel bannerPanel = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
      bannerPanel.add( banner, BorderLayout.CENTER );
      bannerPanel.setBorder( BorderFactory.createTitledBorder( "Welcome" ) );
      add( bannerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER );
   }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: `public class JPTBorderLauncher extends JFrame {`  There is no need to extend frame here.  Just use an instance.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve what you want , you should keep the main method in another class. There You can call `jptborder createAndShowGUI` . For example:

```
public class MainClass
{
  public static void main(String st[])
  {
   javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable()
   {
     @Override
     public void run()
     {
       jptborder.createAndShowGUI();
     }
   });
  }
}
```

And then compile and  run the `MainClass`

Comment: it showed error in 
avax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable()

Comment: @Nachinne_Manche:  My Mistake..I forgot to write `public static void main`..Code is updated now.

Answer (score 1):

Create a file for your main and a file for your `jptborder` class and then reference your class from your main. Ensure that they are in the same package and visible to each other.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            JptBorder border = new JptBorder(); // To use your constructor
            JptBorder.createAndShowGUI(); to use your static method
        }
    });
}
```

Everything else will be in your `JptBorder` class file.